# replacing special chars with .replaceAll

Tags: java, string, escaping, replaceall

Hello I want to replace the following chars within a string

```
String a = "20001=EDTS~^20002=USA~^20003=1170871875~^20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=2~^448=0A";    
System.out.println(a);
String x  = a.replaceAll("~^", "");
System.out.println(x);
```

however my output is:

```
20001=EDTS~^20002=USA~^20003=1170871875~^20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=2~^448=0A
20001=EDTS~^20002=USA~^20003=1170871875~^20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=2~^448=0A
```

So clearly something is up!

I have ran it with the escape chars:

```
 String x  = fix.replaceAll("\\~^", "\\");
```

Still the same output. Is there something associated with the ~ I am unaware of?

I must do the same for:

~!~^

~!

all within the same string I figure 3 .replaceAll longest first then the two others. However I cannot get even the simplest to work :S

EDITED: for some reason the  got removed

Edit2: it should be replacing the ~^ with a character box that looks similar to []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell you don't need a regular expression at all?

If no regular expression is required, you can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` which will also replace all occurences but it won't interpret the first argument as a regular expression (see [String.replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29))

```
String a = "20001=EDTS~^20002=USA~^20003=1170871875~^20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=2~^448=0A";    
System.out.println(a);
String x  = a.replace("~^", "");
System.out.println(x);
```

This will output:

```
20001=EDTS~^20002=USA~^20003=1170871875~^20004=1~^20005=0~^773=~^665=~^453=2~^448=0A
20001=EDTS20002=USA20003=117087187520004=120005=0773=665=453=2448=0A
```

Answer (score 2):

The `^` matches the start of the input string, so your regex `~^` cannot possibly match anything. You'll need to escape it in order to match the literal `"^"`:

```
String x  = a.replaceAll("~\\^", "");
```

Note that the `~` is no special character and needs no escaping.

Or if you want to replace `~!`, `~!~^` and `~^` in one go, try:

```
String x  = a.replaceAll("~!~\\^|~!|~\\^", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

^ in a regular expression means start of line, so I assume java is interpreting it that way, in which case the pattern will never match anything. You need to escape it with a backslash, doubled to get it past java, so "~\\^".